# IE6 and IE7 rendering issues

Tags: cross-browser

How do I get my pages in IE6 and IE7 to render the height like in IE8 and Firefox? right now in both IE8 and Firefox the page dimensions is 1024 x 800 but in IE6 the dimensions are 1024 x 859 and IE7 the dimensions are 1024 x 855.

Comment: Page height will vary depending on toolbars and other variables. The chrome of a browser is your problem not the rendering. Might want to try stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a few reasons for this including padding, margins, and the way that [IE6 treats height as min-height](http://www.virtuosimedia.com/tutorials/ultimate-ie6-cheatsheet-how-to-fix-25-internet-explorer-6-bugs#min-height) (an article I wrote). Try explicitly setting your padding and margins and using the following CSS:

```
#container {min-height:200px; height:auto !important; height:200px;}
```

Comment: Hey when I look at the box model this is what I get 
et: 174px;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
so I imagine that this et property is causing the height error how do I correct that?

Comment: Do you have a doctype? Also, what about the height of the elements within the container? Are any of the child elements floated? The best way that I've found to debug things is to temporarily put a border around each element to see which elements look the way they should and which ones are off. This should help you isolate the problem.

Comment: I put the border around the element and this is what I get et: 174px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; so I imagine that this et property is causing the height error how do I correct that? None of the parent elements has the et propert.

Comment: That is probably the problem. 'et' isn't a CSS property.

Comment: do you know how to get rid of it.